# Insert small line above an item in a list without adding extra space

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, rules, enumitem

I would like to insert a small line between certain items of a list, so that it will look roughly like this:

```
(1) This is the first line

(2) This is the second line
    --------
(3) This is the last line
```

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item This is the first item
    \item This is the second item
    \\ \rule{2cm}{1pt}
    \item This is the last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But, this causes the rule to be placed on its own line, creating a huge space in the list:

[image: Imgur]

How can I draw a line like this without all the extra space, and without ending the enumerate environment?

Also, this part is not a requirement, but is it possible to make the left side of the line align with the left of the labels for the items in the list? e.g.:

```
(1) this is the first line
------------
(2) this is the last line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do this, I want some space added due to the line, but not as much as having the line on a regular-height line would give. Also, I want the line to start at the left of the list.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,expdlist}
\newlist{inferenum}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[inferenum]{%
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  itemsep=.25\baselineskip,
  parsep=0pt,
  labelindent=\parindent,
  leftmargin=*,
  widest={99},
  align=left,
  before*={%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \renewcommand{\listpartsep}{-.5\baselineskip}%
    \renewcommand{\inferline}{%
      \listpart{%
        \hspace{\trythis}\rule{25mm}{0.5pt}%
      }%
    }%
  },
}
\let\sent\item
\newlength{\trythis}
\setlength{\trythis}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\inferline}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{inferenum}
  \sent This is given as one thing.
  \sent This is taken to mean another.
  \inferline
  \sent Finally, the upshot is the result.
\end{inferenum}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: list with line]

Adapting this to your desiderata, you might write, for example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,expdlist}
\newlist{inferenum}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[inferenum]{%
  label={\arabic*.},
  ref={\arabic*},
  itemsep=.25\baselineskip,
  parsep=0pt,
  labelindent=\parindent,
  leftmargin=*,
  widest={99},
  align=left,
  before*={%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \renewcommand{\listpartsep}{-\topsep}%
    \renewcommand{\inferline}{%
      \listpart{%
        \hspace{2\labelindent}\rule{25mm}{0.5pt}%
      }%
    }%
  },
}
\let\sent\item
\newcommand{\inferline}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{inferenum}
  \sent This is given as one thing.
  \sent This is taken to mean another.
  \inferline
  \sent Finally, the upshot is the result.
\end{inferenum}
\end{document}
```

[image: adapted to desiderata]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this? I also defined a `\sepitem` command for an item with a separating line above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\sepitem{\item\raisebox{2.8ex}[0pt]{\rlap{\rule{2cm}{0.8pt}}}}

 \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item This is the first item
\item This is the second item
\item\raisebox{2.8ex}[0pt]{\rlap{\rule{2cm}{1pt}}}%
 This is the last but one item
\sepitem This is the last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks @Bernard! For the future, is it possible to define the first argument of `\raisebox` so that it will keep the line in the middle for any value of `\baselinestretch`, or if `noitemsep` is used?

Comment: Followup Question to this answer: [Insert small line above an item in a list without adding extra space (Continued)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438014/4301)