# Insert small line above an item in a list without adding extra space (Continued)

Tags: lists, enumitem, rules, width

This is a follow up to [Insert small line above an item in a list without adding extra space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341618/4301). I would like to control the length of the horizontal line to be the same widths as the *widest* `\item` in the list.

Below, I am manually passing in the text on which to base the length. While that is an acceptable workaround, I thought I'd see if there was some easy way to eliminate the parameter to `\sepitem`.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}

%% Adapted from 
%%    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341614/
%%            insert-small-line-above-an-item-in-a-list-without-adding-extra-space
\newcommand\sepitem[1]{\item\raisebox{1.90ex}[0pt]{\rlap{\color{orange}\rule{\widthof{#1}}{0.8pt}}}}

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}
\newcommand{\LongText}{Somewhat wider text.}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item \ShortText
\item \ShortText
\sepitem{\ShortText}A
\end{enumerate}
%% -------------------
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item \LongText
\item \ShortText
\sepitem{\LongText}A
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is collecting the text of an `\item`, which I only could solve by redefining it so it takes an argument with the text, i.e. `\item{Text}`. It is not necessary to put the text in braces, but only the part in them (or the first token) is taken into account. Basically, it would suffice to put the longest text in braces.

Instead of `\sepitem` you have to write `\item{\sep Text}`. But with this solution the optional argument of `\item` can be used.

In order to make it work even if the widest item appears after the sep line, the maximum width of the items in an `enumerate` is stored in the file `\jobname.eiw`. This means, you have to compile twice to get the correct length. If you change items you need to again compile twice.

The line length is limited to `\linewidth` to also support multi-line items. But caution, very long texts can lead to a `Dimension too large` error.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{enumscnt}
\setcounter{enumscnt}{0}
\newdimen\max@itemwidth
\newdimen\storedmax@itemwidth
\newdimen\eiw@tempdim
\newbox\eiw@box

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.eiw}{}{}%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw\newwrite\tf@eiw
    \immediate\openout\tf@eiw\jobname.eiw\fi
}

% when reading \jobname.eiw, define macros like e.g.
% \max@item@width.1
\newcommand{\maxitemwidth}[2]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname max@item@width.#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\eiw@before@environment}{%
    \stepcounter{enumscnt}%
    \max@itemwidth0pt\relax
    % prevent error in first run
    \@ifundefined{max@item@width.\the\c@enumscnt}{%
        \maxitemwidth{\the\c@enumscnt}{0pt}%
    }{}%
    % initialize with stored maximum
    \storedmax@itemwidth\csname max@item@width.\the\c@enumscnt\endcsname\relax
}

\newcommand{\eiw@after@environment}{%
    % write new maximum
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\@writefile{eiw}{\string\maxitemwidth{\the\c@enumscnt}{\the\max@itemwidth}}}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\eiw@before@environment}
\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\eiw@after@environment}

\let\orig@item\item

\def\item{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\new@@item}{\new@item}%
}
\def\new@item#1{%
    \getmaxitemwidth{#1}%
    \orig@item #1%
}
\def\new@@item[#1]#2{%
    \getmaxitemwidth{#2}%
    \orig@item[#1] #2%
}

\def\getmaxitemwidth#1{%
    \setbox\eiw@box\hbox{#1}\global\eiw@tempdim\wd\eiw@box
    % limit to \linewidth
    \ifdim\eiw@tempdim>\linewidth
        \eiw@tempdim\linewidth\relax
    \fi
    % get new maximum
    \ifdim\eiw@tempdim>\max@itemwidth
        \global\max@itemwidth\eiw@tempdim\relax
    \fi
    % use bigger of stored or new maximum
    \ifdim\storedmax@itemwidth<\max@itemwidth
        \storedmax@itemwidth\max@itemwidth\relax
    \fi
}

% \sep instead of \sepitem
\newcommand\sep{%
    \raisebox{1.90ex}[0pt]{\rlap{\color{orange}\rule{\storedmax@itemwidth}{0.8pt}}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ShortText}{Short text.}
\newcommand{\LongText}{Somewhat wider text.}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item{\ShortText}
\item{\ShortText}
\item{\sep A}
\end{enumerate}
%% -------------------
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item{\LongText}
\item{\ShortText}
\item{\sep A}
\end{enumerate}
%% -------------------
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item{\LongText}
\item{\ShortText}
\item[x.]{\sep A}
\item{\LongText\ Test}
\end{enumerate}
%% -------------------
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item Somewhat wider text.
\item Short text.
\item[x.] \sep A
\item[y.]{Some very long text, too long for a single line. But one sentece is not enough, so here is another one.}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]